# PHP 5.6 package for debian-8 (Jessie)

Tags: php, ansible, debian-7.6.0

I am writing an ansible script for setting up server in debian 8 , Our existing application is in debian 7 (Wheezy) and the php package is used there is wheezy-php56, The PHP version in the new server is going to be the same. Can I use the same package here ie, wheezy-php56 or is there a jessie-php56 ?

This is the sources.list for Debian 7

> deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
>
> deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
>
> deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all
>
> deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all

What should be sources.list for Debian 8

Comment: What does google say about php packages in Debian 8?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I did not find anything specific for Debian 8.

Comment: A quick google shows this: https://packages.debian.org/stable/php5

Comment: ok, I researched some more and found that php 5.6.7 is already installed in Debian 8 by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Debain 8 already contains the package PHP 5.6.7](https://www.dotdeb.org/2015/04/26/debian-8-0-jessie-has-been-released-and-what-it-means-for-dotdeb/%20%22Debian%208%20already%20includes%20PHP%205.6.7%22%20by%20default.)